# Webjob is causing performance issue with ASP.NET core

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-webjobs

I created a .NET CORE console application and uploaded as a continuous mode webjob to an Azure application (ASP.NET Core). With webjob running, webapp is very slow responding to API request (Request time rise to few seconds).

WebJob code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
queueClient.RegisterMessageHandler(
                async (message, token) =>
                {

                    // Process the message                    
                    // Complete the message so that it is not received again.
                    // This can be done only if the queueClient is opened in ReceiveMode.PeekLock mode.
                    await queueClient.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);


                },
                new MessageHandlerOptions(exce => {
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                })
                { MaxConcurrentCalls = 1, AutoComplete = false });
            //Console.ReadKey();
            while (true) ; 
    }
```

And the processing the message operation takes few seconds.

from SCM console
[image]

Request time
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The `while(true) ;` will pin the CPU so I suggest you don't do that.

Check the Queue message handling example for the proper way how to implement message handling: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Queues

You will have to change your `Main` to:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    JobHost host = new JobHost();
    host.RunAndBlock();
}
```

And then you can make a message handler in another file:

```
public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("logqueue")] string logMessage, TextWriter logger)
{
    logger.WriteLine(logMessage);
}
```

The 3.0.0 preview versions of the [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs/3.0.0-beta3) library support .NET Standard 2.0, so it can be used with .NET Core 2.0 projects.

If you want to implement it yourself, you can check the Webjobs SDK source code for an example how they do it: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/JobHost.cs

Comment: I guess this code is valid for .Net Full framework, .NET Core doesn't have WebJob SDK support yet. Your answer based on WebJob SDK it seems. With .NET Core we have to manually manage everything.

Comment: The 3.0 beta version is compatible with Net Standard 2.0, so it should work.

Comment: I will have a look, I haven't update the application to .Net Core 2.0 yet, as we experimented, we encounter some issues EF core 2.0, waiting for the bugs to fixed.

Comment: Alright, understandable. If you do want to implement this yourself properly, you can check the WebJobs SDK source code: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/JobHost.cs